# Responding to Outlook meeting requests from Emacs

Tags: email, emacs, outlook

I'm trying to read my emails from Emacs, under Linux. I'm using the Notmuch mail client. So far, so good, I managed to send email and even integrated LDAP.

However, I receive Outlook meeting request. I normally response to such emails with the Lighting plugin of Mozilla Thunderbird.

How can I response to Outlook meeting requests from Emacs?